# How to store ammonium perchlorate?

Tags: safety, explosives

How should ammonium perchlorate (AP) be stored safely? The AP at [PEPCON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEPCON_disaster) was stored in plastic and aluminium containers. I seem to remember that the very material of the storage containers (i.e. aluminium and plastic) contributed to the size of the final explosion, although I do not believe it had much to do with the actual cause of the explosion. Since many metals and plastics such as aluminium and HDPE function as a fuel this kind of makes sense to me.

I can think of many ways of making storage safer: Bunker, inert environment, reduced Temperature, explosion proof installation etc... But how should AP be stored properly? What material should be used for the storage of AP?

Comment: [According to the state of New Jersey](https://nj.gov/health/eoh/rtkweb/documents/fs/0109.pdf), "Ammonium Perchlorate is not compatible with STRONG REDUCING AGENTS; STRONG ACIDS (such as HYDROCHLORIC, SULFURIC and NITRIC);
METALS (such as ALUMINUM, COPPER, and POTASSIUM); METAL OXIDES; PHOSPHOROUS; and COMBUSTIBLES."

Comment: @Karsten  I would like to see the person who got idea somebody could want to store NH4ClO4 with metallic potassium, to explicitly warn about it. I have wanted to add they could mention phosphorus, but they did. But it goes along the warning for Microwave oven sold in US, not to dry pets inside.

Comment: Yet this document does not say what compatible choices of containers are. @Poutnik

Comment: I have not pretended they do. But the OP does not mentions  origin nor amount nor packaging mass.

Comment: You can check the MSDS of AP.

Comment: @NilayGhosh No idea why I did not think of this before. I immediately checked, but to my surprise there is no reference to storage materials specifically. I checked 4 different MSDSs. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @Poutnik I did not think the amount would make much of a difference, but I was just thinking about lab use. It could well be that you can safely store it in a PP, HDPE or even a PET bottle, but if AP is soo sensitive, maybe there are requirements to put it in an anti-static bottle. Or the AP is prone to react with certain materials that are commonly used for storage containers. There are acids that need to be stored in PTFE. I simply have no idea. not a clue.

Comment: FRP containers might be a good choice at scale. Ones with conducting layers might be even better My work with explosives is limited to TATB, PETN, HMX and RDX and in all cases, its either A) LDPE/HDPE Bags in HDPE Drums or wooden boxes or at scale in these big FRP tanks or Plastic lined tanks.